# Conjugacy classes of unipotent algebraic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I want to prove the following statement: 
Let $G$ be a unipotent linear algebraic group acting on an affine variety $X$. Then all $G$−orbits are closed in $X$.
The following is what I have done : 
Let $Y$ be a non-closed orbit in $X$. Then $\overline{Y}-Y$ is a non-empty closed subset of $X$, which is transitive under the $G-$action. Hence $k[\overline{Y}-Y]\ne 0$ and $G$ acts on it by left translations. We can find a finite-dimensional vector subspace $V$ of $k[\overline{Y}-Y]$ stable under $G$. Since $G$ is unipotent, we can find a non-zero $f\in V$ fixed by all elements in $G$. In other words,
$$f(g^{-1}x)=f(x)$$
for any $x\in\overline{Y}-Y$ and $g\in G$. Since $f\ne0$, there exists some $y\in\overline{Y}-Y$ such that $f(y)\ne 0$. Since $\overline{Y}-Y$ is $G-$transitive, we know $f(x)\ne0$ for any $x\in\overline{Y}-Y$. Then what should I do? I don't know how it leads to a contradiction.
If you have some ideas, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @Ertxiem - reinstate Monica Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is often called the Kostant--Rosenlicht theorem. It might be easiest to just read the original result. See Theorem 2 on Pg. 221 of [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1961-101-02/S0002-9947-1961-0130878-0/S0002-9947-1961-0130878-0.pdf).